# discord.py bot defining issue/idk whats wrong

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm unsure what's wrong with this code, it could be very obviously wrong but that's why I'm here :). I've has issues with this before so if someone could explain it to me that would be very helpful: so, I'm unsure what effect the naming of the definition has on the code (async def **on_mention** (message):) (the bold part) so if someone could let me know what I should be naming things that would be great. I'll be responding to comments aswell.

````
async def on_mention(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")```
````

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is the bot not responding to mentions? If so, that's because `on_mention` is not a valid event; [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) is. As far as event handlers go, the handler needs to have the same name as the event that is being listened for.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really understand how that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to discord.py docs there is no `on_mention` event but we can make one by using `on_message` event.

so our code should be :

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")
```